# Shell script to convert the date format in a file

Tags: text-processing, date

I would like to convert the date format in file, using a shell script.

Input:

```
S.no|Name|Joining_Date|Address
1|asdasd|09/18/2018|asdas
2|asd|09/18/2018|asdasd
3|asdas|09/18/2018|aadadw
```

Output:

```
S.no|Name|Joining_Date|Address
1|asdasd|18/09/2018|asdas
2|asd|18/09/2018|asdasd
3|asdas|18/09/2018|aadadw
```

Below are the scripts which have tried

Input File:
`cat datesep.txt`  :

```
asdasd|asdasd|asdasd|30/08/2018|sadasd  
asdasd|asdasd|asdasd|12/09/2018|sadasd  
asdasd|asdasd|asdasd|23/06/2018|sadasd  
asdasd|asdasd|asdasd|26/10/2018|sadasd  
asdasd|asdasd|asdasd|23/09/2018|sadasd  
asdasd|asdasd|asdasd|12/07/2018|sadasd
```

cat test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash  
date +'%d-%m-%y'  
DATE=`date +%d`  
MONTH=`date +%m`  
YEAR=`date +%y`  
echo "${MONTH}/${DATE}/${YEAR}"
```

cat test1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash  
SOURCEDATE=`awk -F '|' '{print $4}' /home/work/datesep.txt`  
TEMP=$SOURCEDATE  
echo $TEMP  
DATE=`cut -c 1-2 ${TEMP}`  
MONTH=`cut -c 4-5 ${TEMP}`  
YEAR=`cut -c 7-10 ${TEMP}`  
echo "${MONTH}/${DATE}/${YEAR}"
```

cat test2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash  
awk -F '|' '{print $4}' /home/work/datesep.txt > /home/work/temp.txt  
TEMP=$SOURCEDATE  
echo $TEMP  
DATE=`cut -c 1-2 /home/work/temp.txt`  
MONTH=`cut -c 4-5 /home/work/temp.txt`  
YEAR=`cut -c 7-10 /home/work/temp.txt`  
echo "${MONTH}/${DATE}/${YEAR}"
```

cat test3.sh

```
#!/bin/bash  
awk -F '|' '{print $4}' /home/work/datesep.txt > /home/work/temp.txt  
TEMP=/home/work/temp.txt  
COUNT=`cat ${TEMP} | wc -l`  
echo $COUNT  
echo $TEMP  
LINE_NUM=1  
while read LINE  
do  
        DATE=`awk -F '/' '{print $1}' LINE`  
        MONTH=`awk -F '/' '{print $2}' LINE`  
        YEAR=`awk -F '/' '{print $3}' LINE`  
        echo "${MONTH}/${DATE}/${YEAR}"  
        ((LINE_NUM++))  
done < $TEMP
```

cat test4.sh

```
#!/bin/bash  
awk -F '|' '{print $4}' /home/work/datesep.txt > /home/work/temp.txt  
TEMP=`/home/work/temp.txt`    
for LOOP in `/home/work/temp.txt `  
do  
        DATE=`awk -F '/' '{print $1}' $LOOP`  
        MONTH=`awk -F '/' '{print $2}' $LOOP`  
        YEAR=`awk -F '/' '{print $3}' $LOOP`  
        echo "${MONTH}/${DATE}/${YEAR}"  
done
```

Comment: Hi! What have you tried this far, and where in that process are you stuck?

Comment: I'd recommend you use the date format YYYY-MM-DD, as that ISO-standard format is unambiguous.

Comment: You can use awk, with the `substr()` function or the `split()` function.

Comment: actually am new to working in shell script, just come across with the task, have tried with awk but, am not getting expected output.

Comment: Then please share _what_ you have tried, there are many skilled `awk` hackers (I am not one of them!) around that can give you pointers.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux. **;-)** We're not a script-writing service but we're always willing to help if you're stuck in scripting hell. Also see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VnLFO.gif)

Comment: @Fabby, Thanks for your warm welcome, have added my tries in question part, hope that will help to clear my query

Comment: Much better!  **+1** from me!  (and you've got an answer in the meantime too as it's a clear question now)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working from the first set of given input and expected output in the question and assuming that you'd just want to swap the month and day in the date in the third `|`-delimited field.

```
$ awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' 'NR > 1 { split($3, a, "/"); $3 = sprintf("%s/%s/%s", a[2],a[1],a[3]) } 1' <file
S.no|Name|Joining_Date|Address
1|asdasd|18/09/2018|asdas
2|asd|18/09/2018|asdasd
3|asdas|18/09/2018|aadadw
```

This `awk` command treats each input line as a record with `|`-delimited fields.  It takes the 3rd such field on each line (except the first line) and splits it on `/` into the array `a`.  It then reassembles the field using the `a` array into the wanted format and order using `sprintf()` (which works like `printf()` but returns the generated string instead of outputting it).  The lone `1` at the end causes each line to be outputted (it's a short way of writing `{ print }`).